# Parse ad.size meta tag to parse width / height into integers with JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing, meta-tags

Using JavaScript, how can I get the ad size width and height from a meta tag located in the HEAD section of my HTML file?

in HEAD of HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Returns a string "width=160,height=600"
    var dimensionsStr = document.querySelector('meta[name="ad.size"]')['content‌​'];

</script>
```

How can I parse this string to get:

```
var width = 160;
var height = 600;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extract all "variables" from that content dynamically like this:

```js
// Returns a string "width=160,height=600"
var dimensionsStr = document.querySelector('meta[name="ad.size"]').content;
var obj = dimensionsStr.split(",").reduce( (obj, s) => {
    var [key, value] = s.match(/[^\s;=]+/g);
    obj[key] = isNaN(value) ? value : +value;
    return obj;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<meta name="ad.size" content="width=160,height=600"></meta>
```

This way it also doesn't matter if the order of `width` and `height` is reversed, or you have other variables in that content.

Answer (score 1):

More elegant and efficient way (using split with map):

```
{
  const dimensionsStr = 'width=160,height=600';

  const matched = dimensionsStr.split(',').map(str => parseInt(str.split('=')[1]));
  //[160, 600]

  var [width, heigth] = matched; //ES6 destructuring assignment

  console.log(width, heigth);
  //160 600
}
```

Using regExp:

```
{
  const dimensionsStr = 'width=160,height=600';

  const matched = dimensionsStr.match(/=(.*?),(.*?)=(.*?)$/)
  //["=160,height=600", "160", "height", "600"]

  const width = parseInt(matched[1]),
        heigth = parseInt(matched[3]);

  console.log(width, heigth);
  //160 600
}
```